# Difference between two dates in decimals in postgresql like excel

Tags: postgresql

I am having two dates and i am calculating difference using below query.

select to_date('10042025','mmddyyyy') - to_date('1977-09-27','yyyy-mm-dd');

Output i am getting is 17539

Where as in excel i am getting 17539.8635.

I want to get same output from query also as per the excel.

Comment: Your timestamps do not have times.  There is absolutely no justification for including fractional days.  The correct answer is 17539.  I'm guessing your Excel sheet cells actually have times, but you have the formatting set to hide the time.

Comment: I did check Excel sheet cell property and it is showing only Date

Comment: With ``04.10.2025  20:43:26`` - difference in Excel=17539,86350

Comment: Excel cell formatting can hide details. Your postgres query has calculated an integer numbers of days between to 2 dates, both of those are mmddyyyy or yyyy-mm-dd so neither of them has time of the day, which you would need to get a fractional part of a day returned in the result.

Comment: What is the command/formula you are using in Excel? **Add as update to question**.

Comment: It may only be SHOWING the date, but the cell contains a time.  I guarantee it.  It's a simple fact -- subtracting two dates produces an even number of days.  (That's what 17539 is -- the number of days).  It CANNOT produce a fractional day.